# Generate toString method using OpenApi generator without outputting null values

Tags: java, gradle, openapi-generator

My generator setup looks like this

```
task generateRbsModel(type: GenerateTask) {
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/...openapi.yaml"
    outputDir = "${buildDir}/generate-resources/main"
    modelPackage = "....model"
    generateModelTests = false
    globalProperties = [
            modelDocs: "false",
            apis: "false",
            models: ""
    ]
    configOptions = [
            library: "spring-boot",
            dateLibrary: "java8"
    ]
}
```

I would like to override the toString() method so that when the class object is displayed, the fields c with the value null are not displayed

```
Is it possible to configure the generation of the toString method that will not display fields with null values?
```